# Trying to connect IBM Quantum to External API

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

Is it possible to connect a quantum computer to openlibary.org API? How do I find the public IP address to my quantum instance?

Comment: what's openlibary.org API?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the IBM Quantum OpenAPI specification in
https://runtime-us-east.quantum-computing.ibm.com/openapi/

The `qiskit_runtime` package includes some information on how you can connect to it directly:   https://qiskit.org/documentation/partners/qiskit_runtime/tutorials/API_direct.html